# C++ QT OSX Qt::META+Qt::Key_Tab shortcut bind

Tags: c++, macos, qt, keyboard-shortcuts

I’m trying to bind `Qt::META` + `Qt::Key_Tab` shortcut in `QTabWidget` to switch tabs (like it works in chrome or many other applications). 
I have tried every single solution found in google, but this shortcut combination is not working.

I have tried:

- Combinations like `Qt::Key_Control` + `Qt::Key_Tab`, `Qt::Key_Meta` + `Qt::Key_Tab`, `QKeySequence`(`Qt::Key_Meta`, `Qt::Key_Tab`), `QKeySequence`(`Qt::META`, `Qt::Key_Tab`) etc.
- `QShortcut`
- `QAction`
- capturing keys using virtual `QWidget::event`
- capturing keys using virtual `QWidget::eventFilter` with `installEventFilter`
- all relative like `keyPressed` and etc..

`QWidget::event`/`QWidget::eventFilter` catches <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>, but not <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>(META)+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> I see my `qDebug` output, when I press Ctrl + Tab nothing happens.

Can somebody explain me what is wrong and so special with this particular key combination in QT on OSX?

Doesn't matter what widget, I have created clean GUI project with no other widgets in it - still the same.

Some information:

- OSX Mountain Lion 10.8.5
- QT 5.2

**BTW**, In Qt Creator I’m not able to set <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> shortcut either, thats really ridiculous.

**Note:** It works great on **Windows**, it doesn't work on **OSX**!

I appreciate any help.

Simple code with QAction:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);


    QAction *pAction = new QAction(this);
    QKeySequence keySequence = Qt::META + Qt::Key_Tab; // Not working
    // or
    QKeySequence keySequence = Qt::ALT + Qt::Key_Tab; // Works Alt+Tab
    // or
    QKeySequence keySequence = QKeySequence(Qt::Key_Meta, Qt::Key_Tab); // Not working
    // or
    QKeySequence keySequence = QKeySequence(Qt::META, Qt::Key_Tab); // Not working
    pAction->setShortcut(keySequence);

    connect(pAction, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(shortcut_NextTab()));

    addAction(pAction);

}
```

And slot function:

```
void MainWindow::shortcut_NextTab()
{
    qDebug() << "LOL";
}
```

Expecting to see `LOL` in Application output, when pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Comment: Please post code you have tried, explain what you expected it to do and why it didn't work.

Comment: Added simple piece of code using QAction. I can change Qt::Key_Meta + Qt::Key_Tab for whatever I want and it works, but Ctrl+Tab is not working.

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a bug in Qt on Cocoa. See [QTBUG-8596](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-8596) and [QTBUG-12232](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-12232). The first bug report has a [comment](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-8596?focusedCommentId=215198&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-215198) that says that it works if you add the QAction to the menu. I was experiencing the same problem as you, and that solution worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

In this line:

```
QKeySequence keySequence = Qt::Key_Meta + Qt::Key_Tab;
```

You are just adding integers.  Per [QT documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qkeysequence.html#QKeySequence-4):

> **QKeySequence::QKeySequence ( int k1, int k2 = 0, int k3 = 0, int k4 = 0 )**
>   Constructs a key sequence with up to 4 keys k1, k2, k3 and k4.
>   The key codes are listed in Qt::Key and can be combined with modifiers (see Qt::Modifier) such as Qt::SHIFT, Qt::CTRL, Qt::ALT, or Qt::META.

Meaning:

- if you want a sequence, you need to use two-argument constructor to `QKeySequence`, not just add two integers together (which is what you are doing) and use one-argument constructor.
- If you want a modifier - which I assume means holding a key down - use `QT::Modifier`, not `Qt::Key_*`.

Comment: Ok, thanks for reply, but Qt::META + Qt::Key_Tab doesn't work.
I can add a long list of code I have tried, but I don't think it will be ok.

Comment: @x610 I know it doesn't work. That's what I just told you. Do you know how constructors and initialization with `=` works in C++?

Comment: @x610 in any case I think `QKeySequence::QKeySequence(Qt::Key_Meta, Qt::Key_Tab)` is what you want.

Comment: yeah, I understand what you are saying, but even using QKeySequence::QKeySequence(Qt::Key_Meta, Qt::Key_Tab) is not working, and eventFilter and QWidget::event doesn't show event on Ctrl+Tab.

Comment: @x610 you might have other errors, but I'm 99% sure my post is correct and using `+` is wrong here.

Comment: I wish your post is correct, but it is not working for me.
pAction->setShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt::Key_Meta, Qt::Key_Tab)) - no working
pAction->setShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt::Key_Alt, Qt::Key_Tab)) - not working
pAction->setShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt::ALT, Qt::Key_Tab)) - not working

pAction->setShortcut(Qt::ALT + Qt::Key_Tab) - WORKS
pAction->setShortcut(Qt::META + Qt::Key_Tab) - not working.

Comment: @x610 use `Qt::Modifier`.

Comment: Like this, right?
`QKeySequence::QKeySequence(Qt::META, Qt::Key_Tab)`

Comment: @x610 relevant? http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/platform-api-reference/xml/daily-docs/libqt4/mac-differences.html see note on meta key.

Comment: I know, that Alt is Option mac key, and Control is Command key.
The main problem is META, which is Control on mac, doesn't work with Tab key at all.

Comment: @x610 when you use the code that works on windows, do the claimed corresponding sequences work on a mac?

Comment: On windows META is Windows key, so I'm using Qt::CTRL, on mac phisical Control key is META, and META+TAB is not working on mac only.